# Get ? and & separately Javascript / PHP

Tags: javascript, php

all.

I've got a site that requires two variables in the url. I've had it working up to this point with one variable:
http://example.com/index.php?username=Doofitator

And to extract it, the code:

```
var a = location.href; 
var userNameVar = a.substring(a.indexOf('?username=')+1);
```

However, I now need http://example.com/index.php?username=Doofitator&day=sunday
and I can't figure out how to make it work, or even if that's the correct way to put two strings in the url.

Any ideas? I'd also, if possible, like a way to extract these from the url in php. The following is what I used with one string, however again, can't figure it out with two:

```
$user = $_GET['username'];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $day = $_GET['day'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "username=" and "day=" parts, just change the "+10" and "+5" parts back to "+1"s.

```js
var a = location.href;
a = "http://example.com/index.php?username=Doofitator&day=Sosday"; //Test URL
var userNameVar = a.substring(a.indexOf('?username=')+10,a.indexOf('&day='));
var dayVar = a.substring(a.indexOf('&day=')+5);
console.log("Username: "+userNameVar+", Day: "+dayVar)
```

For PHP, I don't know, but did you try:

$user = $_GET['username'];

$day = $_GET['day'];

Comment: @Doofitator Glad it did. :D

Answer (score 1):

For PHP

```
$user = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : null;
$day= isset($_GET['day']) ? $_GET['day'] : null;
```

For Js

```
var username = getQuery("username");
var day = getQuery("day");

function getQuery(paramter) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
  var pair = vars[i].split("=");
  if (pair[0] == paramter) {
    return pair[1];
  }else{
    return null;
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: You forgot decoding of the value. And possibly of the parameter name, if you want to be pedantic.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `$day = $_GET['day'];` like you did for `username`